# Jquery UI - Nested Droppables/Sortables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to build an interactive web App. using Jquery UI, but I am stuck here - I can't seem to find a way to "Nest" my "boxes" (See fiddle for demo). For example assume there are four boxes - **A**, **B** , **C** , **D**. If A is the parent with high values for width and height, I drag and drop b into **A** - This works fine. I try dragging and dropping another "box" **C** into **A**, which also works fine. But when I try to drop **D** (or even **C**, this doesn't matter) into **B** (Nesting), it doesnt seem to work (See fiddle).

Notice that the fiddle doesn't contain separate "Boxes" but instead just one box thats replicated multiple times. Also note that I haven't implemented the sorting feature (in the fiddle) yet since I haven't been able to fix the nesting issue.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQwsf/

Just to make sure I'm not trying to confuse anyone here, I've attached an image.

[image]

Any help is really much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: And you've made b both draggable AND droppable?  And the "accepts" matches up.  I'd check the fiddled, but this is from my phone...

Comment: No Michael, I think B is just draggable, A is just droppable. Thanks though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hjarvard/JQwsf/5/) what you need?

Summary: the new inner box must be greedy to intercept events.

Comment: Its perfect Sigurd, Thank you so much!! But is it possible to make this chaining infinite, for example, a box within a box within a box within..etc ??

Comment: Yep! You need only to replace the `$temp.appendTo(this);` with your  `appendnow($temp, $(this));` . [Click here to see](http://jsfiddle.net/hjarvard/JQwsf/8/). Also you need to recalculate the dimensions of each dropped box. In the example above I set dimensions like half of the parent. Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: You're one amazing guy. Thanks a million dude. It worked flawlessly! :)

Comment: Here is the link to [Option Greedy](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy) in the JQuery UI documentation.

Comment: @sigurd I am having issue to implement same above problem in [here](https://github.com/frappe/bootstrap-form-builder)