# jQuery UI Dropzone doesnt react to a Draggable thats a Child of another Draggable (Nested Draggables)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a simple Dropzone which accepts Draggables with the class "can_be_dropped". This works fine. But i have a Div with "can_be_dropped" inside another Div that has "can_be_dropped" as the parent.

The Dropzone wont react to the Child Draggable,thats inside a Parentdraggable, if you drop it on the Dropzone.

I created a super simple example Fiddle to show it (i wont get it to react to #itemthree):
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismueller/qzyL9/25/

```
$(".can_be_dragged").draggable();

$("#thedropzone").droppable({
    accept: ".can_be_dropped",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert('You just Dropped #' + $(ui.helper).attr('id'));
    }
});


<div id="thedropzone"></div>
<div class="can_be_dragged can_be_dropped" id="itemone"></div>
<div class="can_be_dragged can_be_dropped" id="itemtwo">
    <div class="can_be_dropped" id="itemthree"></div>
</div>
```

I know for Dropzones theres this "greedy" option (like solved here: [Jquery UI - Nested Droppables/Sortables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559488/jquery-ui-nested-droppables-sortables) ), but is there a solution like this available for Draggables? Im really stuck here and happy for any hints/help.

Currently i think it has to be solved by some CSS workarounds. But currently theres no way around for me for #itemthree to be a child of #itemtwo. I would be happy if its just a jquery setting.

## Short description of the Problem:

The Droppable doesnt react if i drop #itemthree on it which is a child of #itemtwo

Comment: What behavior do you expect when you drop `#itemtwo` into `#thedropzone`?

Comment: i want the dropzone to react to #itemthree (dropping only the blue/violet part). i just seen i should make that clearer. i will edit  the description. #itemone and #itemtwo just react like they should. They trigger the alert in the droppable.

Comment: Your `#itemthree` doesn't drag independently of `#itemtwo`. So you are also dropping `#itemtwo` when `#itemthree` is dropped? What alert message do you expect?

Comment: This is the situation:
#itemone is standalone and does what it should. 

#itemtwo and #itemthree belong together. no matter which area of any of them is dropped should trigger the event. If there is a way for #itemthree triggering the event for #itemtwo thats also ok. I just need to find a way for the droppable to react to #itemthree touching it (without checking coordinates by myself, which would make  the droppable obsolete)

Comment: The way I interpret the documentation is you need to specify `#itemthree` as **draggable**. _"The jQuery UI Droppable plugin makes selected elements droppable (meaning they accept being dropped on by draggables)."_ http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: When you do declare #itemthree again as a draggable its no longer connected to #itemtwo when its dragged. Which you can test here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismueller/KRrvf/2/

The relationship from #itemtwo to #itemthree needs to stay the same. So when #itemtwo or #itemthree is dragged the complete object should move.